# Spring HttpStatus.valueOf seems inefficient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Valueof method goes in a loop over the codes which seems inefficient to me. Am i missing something? 
I am using spring 4.2.5

```
    public static HttpStatus valueOf(int statusCode) {
        for (HttpStatus status : values()) {
            if (status.value == statusCode) {
                return status;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No matching constant for [" + statusCode + "]");
    }
```

Comment: There's only about 60 enum constants. The time it takes to execute the loop is probably insignificant compared the other things the application is doing (e.g. networking). There's not really another way to do this either. I suppose you could try a map but I have no idea if that'd actually be faster—you'd need to profile/benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you asking but yes when compared to later version of Spring there is some modification but logic remains same.

In `Spring 5.1.7` it looks like this 
Refer [Git](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.1.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.java)

```
    public static HttpStatus valueOf(int statusCode) {
        HttpStatus status = resolve(statusCode);
        if (status == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No matching constant for [" + statusCode + "]");
        }
        return status;
    }


    @Nullable
    public static HttpStatus resolve(int statusCode) {
        for (HttpStatus status : values()) {
            if (status.value == statusCode) {
                return status;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The `resolve` method here looks like a decompiled version of the OP's `valueOf` method. In other words, nothings really changed between versions. They've added a `resolve` method which returns null instead of throwing an exception when the constant can't be found, but otherwise the search code is exactly the same.

Answer (score -1):

what is your confusion ? You can ask me . foreach in  values() ,when the statusCode equals
break the loop and return .